# react стили модули

Tags: reactjs, модули

подскажите есть готовая верстка, переношу ее на реакт, и в модулях css если стили к примеру

`.header-top` - `{styles.headerTop}` - он вообще не видит, хотя если переименовать стиль в

`.header_top` - `{styles.header_top}` - то все ок

можно ли как то сделать, чтобы заработало со стилями через - , или их нужно все переименовывать?

Answer (score 0):

css модули не меняют название классов.

Если указан `header-top` - именно `header-top` и нужно использовать:

```
styles['header-top']
```